# How to set the value of a field from a different form on it's unload event?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have two forms(say Form-A and Form-B). On unloading of Form-B, I need to set a value of a field(say Fld-A) present in Form-A. I've tried few approaches but none seem to be working.

1) The most simple way which I tried is this. On the unload event of Form-B, I wrote this code - document.forms["Form-A"]["Fld-A"].value="1". This is not working. The field has the value null.

2) Then I also used @setdocfield on the unload event of Form-B. The formula I used was @setdocfield(@DocumentUniqueId;"Fld-A","1"). Even this doesn't work.

3) Next I used a field on Form-B itself(say Fld-B). On the unload event of Form-B, I wrote the code - document.forms[0].Fld-B.value="1". And then I used this code on the onload event of Form-A - if(document.forms["Form-B"]["Fld-B"].value="1") { document.forms[0].Fld-A.value="1" }. Even this doesn't work.

4) Similarly I also used @getdocfield on Form-A, but still no luck.

Not sure what I'm  missing here. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try @SetDocField(@Text(@DocumentUniqueId);"Fld-A","1"). @SetDocField's first parameter has to be a string.

Comment: Please note that @SetField(@DocumentUniqueId;...) is accessing a document, not a form. This is not a trivial difference, so it's important that you understand it properly. Now, where is this code running? In the Notes client, or in a browser? And are you using XPages or ordinary Notes forms? And tell us what the USER is doing. Just from reading what you've described, I have no idea about that so please describe how these forms and/or documents are being opened and closed. Are they both open simultaneously? Does a button on one form open the other form? Does the user open them separately?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, I'm using ordinary Notes forms, not XPages. My Form-A is actually a $$ViewTemplate Form displaying documents from it's view. When this form unloads(which is when the document gets opened when the user clicks on it), I need to set the value "1" in a field present in the Form-B, which is the form with which this document opens.

Comment: I recommend rewriting your question like this: "How to set a field on a $$ViewTemplate from within a document opened from that template?" and adjusting the details accordingly.

Comment: Oh, wait.  Your comment says "I need to set the value '1' in a field present in the Form-B, which is the form with which this document opens."  But your question "I need to set a value of a field(say Fld-A) present in Form-A."  I'm even more confused than I was before. Sorry, but this is just too confusing. Please rewrite your question to clarify.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, Oh.. yes. Noticed now. Sorry for the mistake in my previous comment. Rewriting it - "My Form-B is actually a $$ViewTemplate Form displaying documents from it's view. When this form unloads(which is when the document gets opened when the user clicks on it), I need to set the value "1" in a field present in the Form-A, which is the form with which this document opens. "

Comment: And in the description of the question I have mentioned - "On unloading of Form-B, I need to set a value of a field(say Fld-A) present in Form-A". So this Form-B is nothing but the $$ViewTemplate Form. When a document is opened(i.e. when the template form unloads), I need to set the value "1" in a field present in the Form-A(This Form-A is the form with which the doc opens). So the code written in the 'On Unload' event of Form-B is: document.forms["Form-A"]["Fld-A"]="1". This is not working.

Comment: I'll try to come back to this later. A little busy right now... Perhaps now that it's been clarified, someone else will beat me to it.